# git equivalent to hg -R?

Tags: git, mercurial

What is the git equivalent to `hg -R`? I want to operate on a repository that isn't rooted in a parent directory of the current working directory.

So far I have `git --git-dir="$a/.git" --work-tree="$a" diff "$a"`, where `$a` is the git repository directory.

Comment: You probably don't want to pass $a to diff.  Other than that looks ok.

Comment: You can also export `$GIT_DIR` and `$GIT_WORK_TREE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have should work. If you're using git 1.8.5 or higher, a simpler alternative is to use the `-C` flag, like this:

```
git -C "$a" diff
```

From the man page:

```
-C <path>
           Run as if git was started in <path> instead of the current working directory. When multiple -C options are given, each subsequent
           non-absolute -C <path> is interpreted relative to the preceding -C <path>.
```